# Extending django user(AbstractEmailUser) model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the extended user model like below..

```
class User(AbstractEmailUser):

    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('First name'),max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Last name'), max_length=128)
    avatar = StdImageField(upload_to='user_avatars/', null=True, blank=True, variations={
        'thumbnail': (settings.AVATAR_THUMBNAIL_WIDTH, settings.AVATAR_THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT, True)
    })
    user_name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,verbose_name=_('User id'), max_length=128)


    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.last_name

    def get_full_name(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_thumbnail_url(self):
        return self.avatar.thumbnail.url if self.avatar else None
```

I want to authenticate all users other than admin using email field and the admin by user_name field in extended user model.....I am using django 1.9

Is there any default way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should create a custom authentication backend. A user before authentication is anonymous so we can't tell if he is an admin or not. The way i think you can do this is to authenticate the users using either username or email, if they are admin user authenticate them whatever they used (username or email), but normal users should use email, if they are not, return None.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

class MyAuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
"""
Authenticate All users if Email is used but just the admin if username is used
"""
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):

        try:
            validate_email(username)
            valid_email = True
            kwargs = {'email': username}
        except:
            valid_email = False
            kwargs = {'username': username}

        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(**kwargs)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            print("User model does not exist!")
            return None

        if valid_email and user.check_password(password):
            print("Email used. Authenticate all users")
            return user

        elif not valid_email and user.check_password(password) and user.is_admin:
            print("Username used. Authenticate admin users")
            return user
        else:
            print("something else return None")
            return None


    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

and in `settings.py` file

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
'app.admin.MyAuthenticationBackend',
]
```

The fields you use for authentication should have unique set to True, and blank and null should be False.

```
email = models.EmailField(
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
)
username = models.CharField(
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    verbose_name=_('User id'), 
    max_length=128,
    unique=True,
)
```